# What's the native snappy library when running jar with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, snappy

There is an Error as notice below when I ran a MapReduce jar in Centos 6.4  .

Hadoop Version is 2.6.0  for 64 bit.

The MapReduce failed,how can I solve this?

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: native snappy library not available: this version of libhadoop was built without snappy support.
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.checkNativeCodeLoaded(SnappyCodec.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.getCompressorType(SnappyCodec.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getCompressor(CodecPool.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getCompressor(CodecPool.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.init(SequenceFile.java:1199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1092)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$BlockCompressWriter.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1442)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat.getSequenceWriter(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.<init>(ReduceTask.java:540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Comment: How you ran the jar?

Comment: in command line: hadoop jar ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile hadoop source code for native libraries. Step by step instructions are provided [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2a2to6lBN14&index=16&list=PLf0swTFhTI8pFYbcZA4bNWCjetRKVubPH).

The video covers validation, compiling the code using maven and using the native libraries.