# native snappy library not available: this version of libhadoop was built without snappy support. while runnig query throgh hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

java.lang.RuntimeException: native snappy library not available: this version of libhadoop was built without snappy support.
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.checkNativeCodeLoaded(SnappyCodec.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.getCompressorType(SnappyCodec.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getCompressor(CodecPool.java:150)

[image]

i am using hadoop 2.7.3 version and hive 2.1.1 version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194038/whats-the-native-snappy-library-when-running-jar-with-hadoop

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you and I solved it.

As the error hint, the problem is libhadoop.so library that is not support snappy when building. When hadoop invoke libhadoop.so's 
`public static native boolean buildSupportsSnappy()`, it will return false. So, we get the error.

> The solution is following [BUILDING.txt](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/BUILDING.txt) to build libhadoop.so supporting snappy.

Good luck.