# could not load snappy native libraries for HBase

Tags: hadoop, compression, hbase, centos6, snappy

I have been trying and reading different blogs but failed to get snappy Libraries check TRUE.
OS in use - CentOs 6.9

**Java Version & Path**

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

[root@hadoop1 bin]# $JAVA_HOME

-bash: /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121: is a directory
```

Output of - **`hadoop checknative -a`**

```
17/10/26 11:16:13 WARN bzip2.Bzip2Factory: Failed to load/initialize native-bzip2 library system-native, will use pure-Java version
17/10/26 11:16:13 INFO zlib.ZlibFactory: Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
Native library checking:
hadoop:  true /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/lib/native/libhadoop.so
zlib:    true /lib64/libz.so.1
snappy:  false
lz4:     true revision:99
bzip2:   false
openssl: false Cannot load libcrypto.so (libcrypto.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)!
17/10/26 11:16:13 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

**`hbase org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeLibraryChecker`**

```
2017-10-26 10:46:07,878 WARN  [main] bzip2.Bzip2Factory: Failed to load/initialize native-bzip2 library system-native, will use pure-Java version
2017-10-26 10:46:07,881 INFO  [main] zlib.ZlibFactory: Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
Native library checking:
hadoop: true /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/lib/native/libhadoop.so
zlib:   true /lib64/libz.so.1
snappy: false
lz4:    true revision:99
bzip2:  false
```

Few statements from : **hbase-env.sh**

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_121"

export HBASE_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/lib/native
```

**(commented for now, tried uncommenting it too)**

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/hbase-1.2.6/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64

export JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/lib/native
```

I have all the *.so required in the required path.

output of -  `ps -ef | grep hbase`   to check the paths checked by HBase for libraries.

[image: the image shows the result of paths considered by hbase processes]

Comment: can you explain problem statement in one liner ?

Comment: `hbase org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeLibraryChecker`
this should return snappy - true, after all the steps i followed through blogs.

Comment: The reason is same as the other question. Maybe my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49770516/6054105) will help you.